# "Table has X columns but Y values were supplied" error

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

This is a python script that creates a menu using TKinter, which then is supposed to communicate with a database made with SQLite

```py
class ConectarBD:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()SQL
        self.criar_tabela()

def criar_tabela(self):
        self.cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MuseuSoftware (
        nome TEXT, 
        autor TEXT, 
        tipo INTEGER, 
        estado TEXT);''')

def inserir_registro(self, usuario)
        self.cur.execute('''INSERT INTO MuseuSoftware VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', usuario)
```

Later down I fill in the "usuario" variable at "inserir_registro" and execute the method...

```py
    def cclicked():
        nome_arte = nome_entry.get()
        nome_autor = autor_entry.get()
        estado = estado_entry.get()
        tipo_entrada = tipo.get()

        entrada = (nome_arte, nome_autor, tipo_entrada, estado)

        banco.inserir_registro(usuario=entrada)


    create_bttn = Button(tab1, text='Adicionar', command=cclicked)
    create_bttn.grid(column=0, row=6)
```

But then it shows me an error message saying "Table MuseuSoftware has 1 columns but 4 values were supplied", even though I made sure to write 4 columns on the "CREATE TABLE" part.

Apologies for any obvious errors, as I am only starting out on coding.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: @AMC is this good enough? "Table MuseuSoftware has 1 columns but 4 values were supplied" was the entire error output I received, though.

Comment: Ignoring python for now, can you show the output of running the SQLite command ‘.schema MuseuSoftware’

Comment: It means that there is only 1 column and not 4 column, maybe you made some mistake in the table creation, I would recommend to drop the table and create the table again. Maybe it was a fault while initial creation but due to `IF NOT EXISTS` it does not create a new table with 4 columns

Comment: I found out the error by myself after a good night of resting.
As it turns out, I didn't drop the table after the first few tests and edits, so it had leftover data which conflicted with the creating of a new table...
Oops!

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same error, I added an extra " next to clients(

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE clients("
    first_name TEXT,
    second_name TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    dni TEXT,
    ")""")
```

Just deleting it made it work

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE clientes(
first_name TEXT,
second_name TEXT,
email TEXT,
dni TEXT,
)""")
```